# While loop in php

Tags: loops, while-loop

I need a help. my code shows result if

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($find)) is true
```

Now i want if Condition is not true then it will show "No Data Found"

like if else

```
if(condition)
 statement1;
else
 statement2;
```

my code is where:

```
<form class="contact_form5" action="search.php" method="post" name="contact_form">
    <ul>


             <h3 align="center">Following search matches </h3>


        <?php

            echo "<table width='650' border='0' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='1' class='black12' align='center' >";
            echo "<tbody class='black12'>";
            echo "<tr class='black12bold'>";
                  echo "<td width='19%' align='left' valign='middle' bgcolor='#AFB7BE'>First Name</td>";
                  echo "<td width='19%' align='left' valign='middle' bgcolor='#AFB7BE'>Last Name</td>";
                  echo "<td width='19%' align='left' valign='middle' bgcolor='#AFB7BE'>Gender</td>";
                  echo "<td width='19%' align='left' valign='middle' bgcolor='#AFB7BE'>Occupation</td>";
                  echo "<td width='19%' align='left' valign='middle' bgcolor='#AFB7BE'>Blood Group</td>";
                  echo "</tr>";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($find)){
                  echo "<tr class='black12bold'>";
                  echo "<td align='left' valign='middle' bgcolor='#EEEEEE'>".$row['DRFname']."</td>";
                  echo "<td align='left' valign='middle' bgcolor='#EEEEEE'>".$row['DRLname']."</td>";
                  echo "<td align='left' valign='middle' bgcolor='#EEEEEE'>".$row['DRGender']."</td>";
                  echo "<td align='left' valign='middle' bgcolor='#EEEEEE'>".$row['DROccupation']."</td>";
                  echo "<td align='left' valign='middle' bgcolor='#EEEEEE'>".$row['DRBloodGroup']."</td>";
            ?>

            <?php
                  echo "</tr>";
            echo "</tbody>";


            }

            echo "</table>";
        ?>
    </li>
    </ul>

</form>
```

Please Give Me Some Idea How Can I do This.Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check here : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

```
if(mysql_num_rows($find) > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($find)) { ... }
} else {
    echo "No Data Found";
}
```

And by the way, mysql_ is deprecated, use at least mysqli or PDO.

Comment: You're welcome @SarwarAlam :) Think to mark this question as answered for other people who may have this problem.